# Why is Nokogiri giving me duplicate results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to scrape data from Craigslist.

This section is supposed to scrape the prices off each row, however it will scrape each price twice, so in my scraped data I get:

```
@listings = [["item1", "price1"], ["item2", "price1"]]

@doc.css('.row').each do |row|
    if /\$[0-9]+/.match(row.text)
      @doc.css('.price').each do |price|
        debugger
          @listings[i] << price.text.delete('$')
          i += 1
          next
      end
    else
      @listings[i] << "n/a"
      i += 1
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sample HTML would be useful. Also, your use of an `i` index hints that the surrounding code can be improved (i.e. it's a bit of a code smell)

Comment: We have to have runnable code that duplicates the problem you're seeing. Asking us to recreate the needed HTML, and figure out how to make the code work (incorrectly) is asking too much of volunteers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@doc.css('.row').each do |row|
  ...
  @doc.css('.price').each do |price|
```

is wrong. Each time your code loops for `row` you're going to return the first occurrence of a tag with `class="price"` in the entire document.

Instead it should be something like:

```
@doc.css('.row').each do |row|
  ...
  row.css('.price').each do |price|
```

Also, this is the wrong way to aggregate nodes into a container:

```
@listings[i] << price.text.delete('$')
i += 1
```

Instead, `@listings` should be defined as an array, and just push onto it:

```
@listings << price.text.delete('$')
```

Since you don't show where you initialize `i`, or `listings`, you'll have to figure out how to make that work. And, as is, there are some real questionable things you're doing, at least in the incomplete code example you gave us.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am a total beginner to rails. I've been doing all kinds of tutorials (mike hartl, rubymonk, codecademy, @schneems) and this is my first real project. It's very hard to figure out everything, especially best practices when no one is holding your hand! My problem is that there are multipe listings and each listing needs 4 separate attributes. Currently '@listings' is an array that gets a new array pushed into every time there is a new listing. My view then goes over each array in '@listings' and uses the internal arrays to display the values for each listing.

Comment: Also virtually all of the code for my program is in this one controller! I know I'm supposed to have a skinny controller but the code I'm writing makes no sense in a model (at least not to me) and I definitely don't want it cluttering the view. Any tips?

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with Rails per se, it's pure Ruby, just as Rails is pure Ruby. Rails is a *much* harder learning curve, so if you aren't familiar with Object-Oriented programming and Ruby already, you should save your sanity and spend some time concentrating on Ruby alone. Once you have it figured out Rails is immensely easier because, what seemed like mystifying black-magic will suddenly be understandable as Ruby's ability to dynamically create classes and methods.

Comment: As far as how you're writing your code, I'm not even going to attempt to imagine or visualize it based on a couple sentences. You'll need to create a thorough explained, and documented, question and post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, where they do critiques and will suggest better ways to do things.

Comment: had no idea that place even existed. thank you.